# Carregar arquivos .so no Xamarin Android

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin.android, mono

Estou tentando converter uma classe `Java` para `C#` no `Xamarin.Android`.

A classe `Java` é essa:

```
private native boolean OpenDeviceCtx(Object obj);
public native boolean CloseDevice();
public native boolean GetDiodesStatus(byte[] bArr);
public native boolean GetFrame(byte[] bArr);
public native boolean GetImage(int i, byte[] bArr);
public native boolean GetImage2(int i, byte[] bArr);
public native boolean GetImageByVariableDose(int i, byte[] bArr);
public native boolean GetImageSize();
public native boolean GetInterfaces(byte[] bArr);
public native String GetVersionInfo();
public native boolean IsFingerPresent();
public native boolean OpenDevice();
public native boolean OpenDeviceOnInterface(int i);
public native boolean Restore7Bytes(byte[] bArr);
public native boolean RestoreSecret7Bytes(byte[] bArr, byte[] bArr2);
public native boolean Save7Bytes(byte[] bArr);
public native boolean SaveSecret7Bytes(byte[] bArr, byte[] bArr2);
public native boolean SetDiodesStatus(int i, int i2);
public native boolean SetGlobalSyncDir(String str);
public native boolean SetLogOptions(int i, int i2);
public native boolean SetNewAuthorizationCode(byte[] bArr);
public native boolean SetOptions(int i, int i2);

static {
    System.loadLibrary("usb-1.0");
    System.loadLibrary("ftrScanAPI");
    System.loadLibrary("ftrScanApiAndroidJni");
}
```

Os arquivos `.so` são estes carregados através da `System.loadLibrary`:

**usb-1.0**
 **ftrScanAPI**
**ftrScanApiAndroidJni**

Eu acho que os métodos "nativos" são os métodos dentro dos arquivos `.so`. Estou correto?

Então, para carregar esses arquivos no meu projeto `Xamarin.Android`, eu tentei isso:

```
[DllImport("usb-1.0")]
public static extern int GetUSB();
[DllImport("ftrScanAPI")]
public static extern int GetScanAPI();
[DllImport("ftrScanApiAndroidJni")]
public static extern int GetScanAPIAndroidJNI();
```

E criei a estrutura das pastas assim: **project/lib/arm/files.so**

Quando eu rodo o projeto, aparecem vários erros:

```
DllImport attempting to load: 'usb-1.0'.
DllImport error loading library '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/RDScanFingerprint.RDScanFingerprint/files/.__override__/libusb-1.0': 'dlopen failed: library "/data/app/RDScanFingerprint.RDScanFingerprint-1/lib/arm//storage/emulated/0/Android/data/RDScanFingerprint.RDScanFingerprint/files/.__override__/libusb-1.0" not found'.
DllImport error loading library '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/RDScanFingerprint.RDScanFingerprint/files/.__override__/libusb-1.0.so': 'dlopen failed: library "/data/app/RDScanFingerprint.RDScanFingerprint-1/lib/arm//storage/emulated/0/Android/data/RDScanFingerprint.RDScanFingerprint/files/.__override__/libusb-1.0.so" not found'.
DllImport error loading library '/system/lib/libusb-1.0': 'dlopen failed: library "/data/app/RDScanFingerprint.RDScanFingerprint-1/lib/arm//system/lib/libusb-1.0" not found'.
DllImport error loading library '/system/lib/libusb-1.0.so': 'dlopen failed: library "/data/app/RDScanFingerprint.RDScanFingerprint-1/lib/arm//system/lib/libusb-1.0.so" not found'.
DllImport error loading library 'libusb-1.0': 'dlopen failed: library "/data/app/RDScanFingerprint.RDScanFingerprint-1/lib/arm/libusb-1.0" not found'.
DllImport error loading library 'libusb-1.0.so': 'dlopen failed: library "/data/app/RDScanFingerprint.RDScanFingerprint-1/lib/arm/libusb-1.0.so" not found'.
DllImport error loading library 'usb-1.0': 'dlopen failed: library "/data/app/RDScanFingerprint.RDScanFingerprint-1/lib/arm/usb-1.0" not found'.
DllImport error loading library '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/RDScanFingerprint.RDScanFingerprint/files/.__override__/libusb-1.0': 'dlopen failed: library "/data/app/RDScanFingerprint.RDScanFingerprint-1/lib/arm//storage/emulated/0/Android/data/RDScanFingerprint.RDScanFingerprint/files/.__override__/libusb-1.0" not found'.
DllImport error loading library '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/RDScanFingerprint.RDScanFingerprint/files/.__override__/libusb-1.0.so': 'dlopen failed: library "/data/app/RDScanFingerprint.RDScanFingerprint-1/lib/arm//storage/emulated/0/Android/data/RDScanFingerprint.RDScanFingerprint/files/.__override__/libusb-1.0.so" not found'.
DllImport error loading library '/system/lib/libusb-1.0': 'dlopen failed: library "/data/app/RDScanFingerprint.RDScanFingerprint-1/lib/arm//system/lib/libusb-1.0" not found'.
DllImport error loading library '/system/lib/libusb-1.0.so': 'dlopen failed: library "/data/app/RDScanFingerprint.RDScanFingerprint-1/lib/arm//system/lib/libusb-1.0.so" not found'.
DllImport error loading library 'libusb-1.0': 'dlopen failed: library "/data/app/RDScanFingerprint.RDScanFingerprint-1/lib/arm/libusb-1.0" not found'.
DllImport error loading library 'libusb-1.0.so': 'dlopen failed: library "/data/app/RDScanFingerprint.RDScanFingerprint-1/lib/arm/libusb-1.0.so" not found'.
DllImport error loading library 'libusb-1.0': 'dlopen failed: library "/data/app/RDScanFingerprint.RDScanFingerprint-1/lib/arm/libusb-1.0" not found'.
DllImport unable to load library 'dlopen failed: library "/data/app/RDScanFingerprint.RDScanFingerprint-1/lib/arm/libusb-1.0" not found'.
DllImport attempting to load: 'usb-1.0'.
DllImport error loading library '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/RDScanFingerprint.RDScanFingerprint/files/.__override__/libusb-1.0': 'dlopen failed: library "/data/app/RDScanFingerprint.RDScanFingerprint-1/lib/arm//storage/emulated/0/Android/data/RDScanFingerprint.RDScanFingerprint/files/.__override__/libusb-1.0" not found'.
DllImport error loading library '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/RDScanFingerprint.RDScanFingerprint/files/.__override__/libusb-1.0.so': 'dlopen failed: library "/data/app/RDScanFingerprint.RDScanFingerprint-1/lib/arm//storage/emulated/0/Android/data/RDScanFingerprint.RDScanFingerprint/files/.__override__/libusb-1.0.so" not found'.
DllImport error loading library '/system/lib/libusb-1.0': 'dlopen failed: library "/data/app/RDScanFingerprint.RDScanFingerprint-1/lib/arm//system/lib/libusb-1.0" not found'.
DllImport error loading library '/system/lib/libusb-1.0.so': 'dlopen failed: library "/data/app/RDScanFingerprint.RDScanFingerprint-1/lib/arm//system/lib/libusb-1.0.so" not found'.
DllImport error loading library 'libusb-1.0': 'dlopen failed: library "/data/app/RDScanFingerprint.RDScanFingerprint-1/lib/arm/libusb-1.0" not found'.
DllImport error loading library 'libusb-1.0.so': 'dlopen failed: library "/data/app/RDScanFingerprint.RDScanFingerprint-1/lib/arm/libusb-1.0.so" not found'.
DllImport error loading library 'usb-1.0': 'dlopen failed: library "/data/app/RDScanFingerprint.RDScanFingerprint-1/lib/arm/usb-1.0" not found'.
DllImport error loading library '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/RDScanFingerprint.RDScanFingerprint/files/.__override__/libusb-1.0': 'dlopen failed: library "/data/app/RDScanFingerprint.RDScanFingerprint-1/lib/arm//storage/emulated/0/Android/data/RDScanFingerprint.RDScanFingerprint/files/.__override__/libusb-1.0" not found'.
DllImport error loading library '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/RDScanFingerprint.RDScanFingerprint/files/.__override__/libusb-1.0.so': 'dlopen failed: library "/data/app/RDScanFingerprint.RDScanFingerprint-1/lib/arm//storage/emulated/0/Android/data/RDScanFingerprint.RDScanFingerprint/files/.__override__/libusb-1.0.so" not found'.
DllImport error loading library '/system/lib/libusb-1.0': 'dlopen failed: library "/data/app/RDScanFingerprint.RDScanFingerprint-1/lib/arm//system/lib/libusb-1.0" not found'.
DllImport error loading library '/system/lib/libusb-1.0.so': 'dlopen failed: library "/data/app/RDScanFingerprint.RDScanFingerprint-1/lib/arm//system/lib/libusb-1.0.so" not found'.
DllImport error loading library 'libusb-1.0': 'dlopen failed: library "/data/app/RDScanFingerprint.RDScanFingerprint-1/lib/arm/libusb-1.0" not found'.
DllImport error loading library 'libusb-1.0.so': 'dlopen failed: library "/data/app/RDScanFingerprint.RDScanFingerprint-1/lib/arm/libusb-1.0.so" not found'.
DllImport error loading library 'libusb-1.0': 'dlopen failed: library "/data/app/RDScanFingerprint.RDScanFingerprint-1/lib/arm/libusb-1.0" not found'.
DllImport unable to load library 'dlopen failed: library "/data/app/RDScanFingerprint.RDScanFingerprint-1/lib/arm/libusb-1.0" not found'.
```

Alguma ideia do que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Vi que você fez a mesma pergunta no SOen, e lá tem algumas soluções propostas. Se alguma delas funcionar, poste como resposta depois aqui.

Comment: @GrupoCDSInformática com certeza!